# Send key win + E

Tags: windows, perl

I tried to do a shortcut from cmd (perl windows)
This work partially but not open the windows explorer.

```
 use Win32::GuiTest;
 Win32::GuiTest::SendKeys("{LWI}E");
```

This open the windows star menu then write E
I want to open directly the windows explorer, I tried so many commands but nothing works. Can you give some advice?

Comment: Do you maybe want to launch an Explorer process? Then it's much easier to launch it via `system 'explorer.exe';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to start explorer is to just start explorer:

```
system 'explorer.exe';
```

But if you really want to use Win32::GuiTest, here's something that works:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Win32::GuiTest qw(SendKeys SendRawKey :VK);

SendRawKey VK_LWIN, 0;
SendKeys 'e';
SendRawKey VK_LWIN, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
```

The issue is that `SendKeys` emits keydown/keyup events for every single character. We need separate keydown and keyup events for the <kbd>Win</kbd> key, surrounding the inner <kbd>E</kbd>